# Why does this code continue (recursion)?

Tags: java, recursion, return, return-value

First of all I want to say that I know that this is the worst solution for solving my problem, however I just want to get familiar with recursion. I want to check if a sequence is DNA (So it can only contain A,T,G or C). My code:

```
public Boolean check(String seq) {
    System.out.println(seq);
    Boolean correct = true;
    Character letter = seq.charAt(seq.length() - 1);
    if ("ATGC".contains(letter.toString())) {
        if (seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1).length() > 0) {
            check(seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1));
        }

    } else {
        correct = false;

    }
    System.out.println(seq + " " + correct);
    return correct;
}
```

However when I run the code it will continue running after changing the `correct = false`. To make this clear I will paste the output of the print statements:

```
ATXGCTGC
ATXGCTG
ATXGCT
ATXGC
ATXG
ATX
ATX false
ATXG true
ATXGC true
ATXGCT true
ATXGCTG true
ATXGCTGC true
```

The Boolean which is returned is `true`, however the code should have stopped after `ATX false`. **What** went wrong and **how** to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `return`-ing the recursive call?

Comment: wow that was the problem hahaha, thankyou! @cricket_007 can you explain what happend here (post it as an answer so I can accept it maybe it will help some other people out)

Comment: you did not define your base case

Answer (score 1):

It's ok. The thing which you call 'keeps running' is just how recursion works. If you watched inception movie that can help you as a metaphor.

Functions calls itself a number of times (your first `println` statement marks that), then once the recursion end condition is met at some level, function will return the execution to the calling stack frame (that is what captured by your second `println`).

With a simpler example of "AA":

1. check("AA") runs the first println, then it runs check("A")
2. check("A") runs first println too, at that time the condition prevents further recursion, so the execution proceeds to the second println statement
3. function call returns and now we're back to our check("AA") call in the line after the check function
4. execution proceeds and you see 2nd println pointing the results

P.S. One problem you have is that you ignore the return result by the function.

Answer (score 1):

You discard the result of the recursive call to `check`. Hence even if check returns `false` that information is lost. And since the branch in which `check` is called never sets `correct` it will retain its initialization value (`true`).

As far as I can tell by quick glance the solution would be as simple as assigning `correct` the return value of `check`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check if it returned `false`. You need to make an if statement that ends the methods when `check()` returns `false`

Answer (score 1):

By just calling

```
check(seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1));
```

You re doing what you want, however when that recursion returns, that method continues running out (as you see when the string is "growing" in the output).

If you increase use

```
return check(seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1));
```

or maybe

```
correct = check(seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1));
```

you may get the output you want. You can use a debugger to diagnose which one makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You have no condition to terminate when a wrong character is encountered. A proper recursive approach would be as follows:

1. If a string is empty - it's OK
2. If not, check the first character:

   - If it's not one of the "ATGC" characters, return false
   - If it is, recursively apply the algorithm on a substring starting from the second character:

```
private static Set<Character> LEGAL_CHARS = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'T', 'G', 'C'));

public boolean check(String seq) {
    if (seq.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!LEGAL_CHARS.contains(seq.charAt(0))) {
        return false;
    }
    return check(seq.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: this looks a lot neater and clearer than my code! thankyou for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the line

`if (seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1).length() > 0) {
    check(seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1));
}`

to

`if (seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1).length() > 0) {
    return check(seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1));
}`

This would return your check result back to upper level recursion function,

which in the end is the desired outcome.

**why do i need to return check function?**

when you called check function inside the if check it create a new recursive call which is queued in the stack with its variables. when it returns a result you simply ignored it(did not store the result). To use the value of the lowest level recursion function you need to pass its value back to its parent recursion call made.SO in the end you have the result.